# Chartboost iOS SDK integration to cocos2d-x 3

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x, chartboost

I have done all steps according to the Chartboost documentation to integrate iOS SDK to my app. But at the last stage of calling Chartboost I have a compile error:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {


    // Begin a user session. Must not be dependent on user actions or any prior network requests.
    // Must be called every time your app becomes active.
    [Chartboost startWithAppId:@"some_id" appSignature:@"some_signature" delegate:self];

    // Show an ad at location "CBLocationHomeScreen"
    [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
```

On the call of `startWithAppId` method I get the following error:

`......../proj.ios_mac/ios/AppController.mm:101:126: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<ChartboostDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 'AppController *'`

Comment: AppController interface definition does not include the Chartboostdelegate protocol

Comment: I have done this: `@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, ChartboostDelegate> {` it worked. Thanks!

Comment: your second method doesn't work, because you mix methods of 5.x and older versions of Chartboost iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

Instead,

try using this code

```
Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];

cb.appId = @"some_id";
cb.appSignature = @"some_sig";

[cb startSession];

[cb showInterstitial];
```

Comment: As you could see, author use Chartboost 5.x version, so your code is useless

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answered for anyone that might come across this thread. Tested to be working on 2/16/2015 for Chartboost *Version 5.1.3*

In your appController.mm file add the following imports:

```
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

Next add the following interface:

```
@interface AppController () <ChartboostDelegate>
@end
```

Finally in  your applicationDidBecomeActive Method add:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [Chartboost startWithAppId:@"appID" appSignature:@"appSIG" delegate:self];
    [Chartboost showInterstitial:CBLocationHomeScreen];
    //[Chartboost showInterstitial:@"CBLocationHomeScreen"]; //older way
}
```